# почему не исчезает Declaration or statement expected?

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular

Этот кусок кода вызывает ошибку
`TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.`
Перезапускал скрипт npm, перепроверял фигурные скобки, но ошибка все равно не исчезает. На работу приложения не влияет никак, но ошибка раздражает глаза. Как это можно пофиксить?

```js
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import {AppComponent} from './app.component';
import {ProgrammerModule} from "./modules/programmer.module";
import {ProgrammerComponent} from './components/programmer/programmer.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ProgrammerComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    ProgrammerModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Вы какой IDE пользуетесь? Если WebStorm, то на англоязычных сайтах говорят, что им помогал очень часто перезапуск WebStorm

Comment: @EzioMercer Спасибо за совет. Вроде помогло

Comment: Обращайтесь :) Часто IDE таким образзом путают людей и на отладку уходит много времени

Comment: Если не трудно, отметье пожалуйста мой ответ полезным и принятым, буду очень признателен!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте перезапустить вашу IDE, должно помочь, если у вас WebStorm (скорее всего и в других IDE это сработает), так советуют на англоязычных сайтах

Answer (score 2):

Если проблема в webstorm, нажмите по вкладке Typescript (обычно находится в нижней правой части экрана), затем Restart Typescript Service.